# Am I violating the Google Play Developer Program Policies by launching another application?

Tags: android, google-play

I feel confuse with the **Google Play Developer Program Policies**. I have 2 applications. When I click a button in Application A, it starts Application B.

The **Google Play Developer Program Policies** however states the following:

> **System Interference:** Apps and their ads must not modify or add browser
>   settings or bookmarks, add homescreen shortcuts, or icons on the
>   user’s device as a service to third parties or for advertising
>   purposes.

Am I violating that policy by creating a function to go to the other application?

Comment: What makes you think you might have violated the Google Play Developer Program Policies? Did your app get removed from the Google Play Store, or where you notified of a violation in some other way?

Comment: thanks Bjarke Freund-Hansen  .  I read **Google Play Developer Program Policies**. and i found policy. **System Interference:** _Apps and their ads must not modify or add browser settings or bookmarks, add homescreen shortcuts, or icons on the user’s device as a service to third parties or for advertising purposes._ .

Comment: I updated your question such that it reflect what I believe you are asking. Please edit the question if I have misunderstood your intention.

Comment: thanks for an update on the my question.  my english is very bad. ^^. thanks you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you didn't violate enything. As far as I know it's OK to do that. If it wasn't OK it wouldn't be so easy. Pretty many apss do that in some form or another. Like when you upload a file from your browser it has to start a filemanager to pick your file. So anyway it's OK to start another app from your app.

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely allowed to make a button in `Application 1` that launch `Application 2`.

What the policy states is that you may not install icons on the homescreen, browser bookmarks or the like which links to advertisers. So you cannot install a "Cheep viagra" shortcut on the users home-screen, but you can add a "Play xxx-game" as a short-cut on the home screen.

It is most probably to prevent and be able to remove apps which spams the user with unwanted advertisements.